# Disable Chrome Color Management - CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors, rgb

I am developing a widget which utilizes exact color values, anything different and the results are incorrect. After spending time tracking down why Chrome is incorrect, I found that Chrome is probably applying color management to my colors.

If I load up my canvas in Edge (the Chromium based version), and load up the canvas in Chrome, I then do a snippet and load it up in Gimp. For Edge my 100% green appears to be RGB(0, 255, 0), for Chrome my 100% green appears to be (0, 255, 60).

Unfortunately, while this kind of color management is a good thing, it is entirely the wrong thing for my application. Is there a generic way to disable color management or a way to probe what the end correction will be so I can counteract it? Kind of messed up that you can't tell a browser to just display a color in the exact way you want.

As an example, Chrome inspector says my CSS is RGB(0, 255, 0), yet, it is rendering a different color in browser. If this is not color management, then why? If it is color management, I would like to override it, as it is 'correcting' the color into incorrectness.

Edit:
Further research shows this is maybe from a recent update:
https://www.faqforge.com/windows/fixed-google-chrome-wrong-color-after-update/

Curious if this is future intended behavior or just a temporary bug.

Edit 2: Forcing Chrome to sRGB fixed the issue on my browser. Sounds like Chrome maybe is defaulting to a non-standard color profile with a recent release.